# Can I use "they" for an inanimate subject?

Tags: word-choice

Example sentence: "They/these were subjected to intensive use during geomorphological evolution."

I'm talking about "deltas". Can I use "they" here?

Comment: Inanimate objects are third person. *They* is a third-person plural pronoun, so in that case it is totally correct.

Comment: It was concise explanation. I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.   The word "They" can be used to reference inanimate objects.

Example:

I have six apples.  They are on the kitchen counter.